# Alfa Romeo Giulia 2.2 JTDM (952) Filter Blow By Oil Vapour Separator Bolt - Torque specs?

Tags: alfa-romeo

`Alfa Romeo Giulia 2.2 JTDM (type 952)`

`Filter Blow By Oil Vapour Separator Bolt`

Hi, does maybe anyone knows torque specs for this bolt?

EDIT: The screw is **T25**

Comment: What size is the bolt?

Comment: Ok I'll soon clarify the problem.